# How to return List<Impl> for List<interface>

Tags: java

The following code is pretty useless and not tested. It should only explain the problem.
I want to hide the implementing classes from the application, but define the hierarchy.

Given following interfaces

```
public interface RowType {
    Integer getSumFromHere();
}

public interface TableType {
    List<RowType> getRows();
}
```

Implemented by

```
public class RowImpl implements RowType {

    private Integer value = 0;
    private RowImpl nextRow;

    public RowImpl someFunctionNotInInterface() {
        return nextRow;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getSumFromHere() {       
        return nextRow == null ? value : value + nextRow.getSumFromHere();
    }
}

public class TableImpl implements TableType {

    List<RowImpl> implList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void doSomethingOnImpl (){
      for(RowImpl row : implList) {
        row.someFunctionNotInInterface();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public List<RowType> getRows() {
        return implList;
    }  
}
```

The implementation of getRows() leads to an error `"cannot convert from List<RowImpl> to List<RowType>"`
In fact, it`s guaranteed that every entry in the implList can be accessed through the interface RowType, so it could work.

I tried `<? extends RowType>` but that's not compatible to the TableType interface.
Of course I can simple solve the problem, by copying the list `return new ArrayList<>(implList);` but that's not the same as having a reference to the list held by the class.

Is there a solution for this, or is the design completely wrong ?

edit: Added function in TableImpl that clarifies why the list is build on RowImpl and not on RowType.

Comment: Why don't you parameterize `getRows` by the type of row it should contain?

Comment: You could simply cast the list. But do you have an actually reason to have `List<RowImpl>` instead of `List<RowType>`?

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta: yes, I must have access to the full implementaiton

Comment: Question: why don't you make `TableType` a generic interface? `interface TableType<T extends RowType> { List<T> getRows();}` this should solve all issues you have...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`implList` is a `List<RowImpl>` and should contain only `RowImpl` instances.

The `List<RowType>` you return has an `add(RowType)` method, for example, that could be used to add `RowType` instances that are *not* `RowImpl`.

For this reason, `List<RowType>` is *not* a supertype of `List<RowImpl>` and you will have to cast `implList` if you want to return it.

At the same time, you should make sure that it is not modified by the caller, so that it really can only contain `RowImpl` instances.

The Collections.unmodifiableList() method does both of those jobs:

```
@Override
public List<RowType> getRows() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(implList);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the point I wasn't aware of. Now it's clear why it cant work.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution from where you are could be just type-casting your list elements:

```
public class TableImpl implements TableType {

    List<RowImpl> implList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public List<RowType> getRows() {
        return implList.stream().map(e -> (RowType) e).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }  
}
```

A better solution, though, can involve redesigning your API, to make `TableType` aware of the type of `RowType` it holds. This is only good if you allow code that calls `getRows()` to know about the implementation class `RowImpl` (otherwise the previous solution is suitable).

```
public interface TableType<T extends RowType> {
    List<T> getRows();
}
```

With this, your implementation class can use `RowImpl` by implementing this version of the interface in this way:

```
public class TableImpl implements TableType<RowImpl> {

    List<RowImpl> implList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public List<RowImpl> getRows() {
        return implList;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the generic type to

```
List<RowType> implList = new ArrayList<>();
```

rather than:

```
List<RowImpl> implList = new ArrayList<>();
```

When inserting an element into the `List`, you can guarantee that it has the required type. For example:

```
implList.add(new RowImpl());
```

Comment: Please follow this link which explains polymorphism for generic types:
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/03/polymorphism-in-java-generics.html

Comment: @Glains Yes, right, I forgot to clarify that I must have access to the Impl definition within the implementations. When I maintian the List as RowType I can no longer access the  not interfaced methods.